# Add border to odd div's using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a html like

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="single_wrap">
     <div class="single_div">
         <p>some text</p>
     </div
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
     <div class="single_div">
         <p>some text</p>
     </div
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
     <div class="single_div">
         <p>some text</p>
     </div
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
     <div class="single_div">
         <p>some text</p>
     </div
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.wrap { float:left; width:100%;}
.single_wrap { float:left; width:50%; padding:15px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
.single_div { float:left; width:100%; border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
```

now what I want to achieve is border-right to every odd .single_div and border-bottom to all but last two .single_wrap.
How to achieve this using CSS. I know nth selector but it doesnt work. as i tried something like this

```
.single_wrap .single_div:nth-child(odd) { border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Comment: What is your browser you are testing in it?

Comment: Please coorect your code. Use {} instead of () for css declarations. Is this the desired result? http://jsfiddle.net/yz7a052x/

Comment: ya sorry @CatalinLungu. I mistyped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check your markup, since there're unclosed `div`. Then for your purpose on recent/modern browser you could do it like so

```
/* right border on all odd single_div */
.single_wrap:nth-child(2n + 1) .single_div {
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
}

/* bottom border on first n-2 single_wrap */
.single_wrap:nth-last-child(n + 3) {
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;  
}
```

Example fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMVgM

Answer (score 1):

Use `.single_wrap:nth-child(odd) .single_div` selector. For `border-bottom` use `:nth-child(1)` and `nth-child(2)`.

```css
.wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.single_wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.single_div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.single_wrap:nth-child(odd) .single_div {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.single_wrap:nth-child(1) .single_div, .single_wrap:nth-child(2) .single_div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="single_wrap">
    <div class="single_div">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
    <div class="single_div">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
    <div class="single_div">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="single_wrap">
    <div class="single_div">
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not an ideal solution for the border-bottom: what if he adds new blocks?

Comment: content is dynamic so border-bottom solution will not work as @Fabrizio Calderan said